# LinkedIn redirect share request to my iPhone app

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, linkedin-api

I am developing an application and needs to open a link in safari (I do not want to use web view in my application). Users do an action and after that the tab that was opend, close automatically. after closing tab I need to open my app.

How can I do this?

---

Edited:
The last API of Facebook, to login redirect users to facebook app or safari app and shows the login page, after login, the facebook app or safari would be closen and then my app open. I need open a link on safari and after closing tab, my app open again.

Comment: Are you using [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url] now?

Comment: @0x7fffffff I have searched about it but I did not find this, thanks

Comment: @ratul I don't start imalementing this, I searched posibility and how do I it, at first...

Comment: Sorry, But I'm confused whether you want to open the app from safari, or open safari from app.

Comment: @ratul I want open safari from my app (It is easy with the code you wrote above) and I want open a link that will be close after user clicks on a button, I want after closing this link (tab), my app opens automatically.

Comment: http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html is this what you are in search of?

Comment: @ratul No, It is not solved!

Comment: Have you checked that url? That tutorial might help you.